# WindowsPhone Native Application - Compatibilities with Javascript / HTML5 / Canvas / CSS 3

Tags: javascript, css, windows-phone-8, webview, html5-canvas

I'm a beginner in the windows phone native applications.
I would like to create view (after my login view) which could support web languages such as HTML 5 / Canvas / JavaScript / CSS3 / and libraries (JS). I didn't make a lot of code, but I saw in the VS2013 that I could create a "Windows Phone App" OR "Windows Phone HTML5 App".
I would like to have the greatest optimized app (the web view will be loaded from internet to avoid application update every day or weeks in the best cases.

Does anyone could suggest me the better way to do ? 
And If it's possible to run Web languages in the classic windows phone application?

Thanks

Comment: I think what you want is RSS feed for windows application. Search for it on web.

Comment: I don't think it could work, I'm developing HTML 5 canvas games which will be downloaded from the server and display on the potential "webview"

Comment: I need to have at least some javascript code on the client side to manage the protocol

Answer (score 0):

you can do with the help of "Windows Phone SDK". just install it in to your windows phone...and u can do...its pretty much easy...

NOTE: Need to turn on IsScriptEnabled in the WebBrowser control in your MainPage.xaml

All the best

Comment: thanks I will try that ! I will let some feedback later